# How to change selection frame color in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, colors

with large multi-colored data, the color of the selection is very weak, and it takes effort to understand where my selection is
[image]

I searched on the Internet how to change the color of the selection through vba. Many codes only change the color of the cell border itself or the background color of the selection, but not the selection which remains green. Need vba code or tips for app that can change color.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel object model doesn't provide anything for that. You may try to play with system colors.